# Customizing UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, textfield, profile

I want a UITextField, but in a much more modern version like the following:

[image]

How might I do this? Create a subclass? What properties would I use?

Comment: its the tableview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Yes that's a tableview. But UITextField inside it's cell. Isn't it ?

Comment: @ParthoBiswas  - yes we can add the each cell has each text field, and add the background image for textfied thats all, on textfield delegate didbeginediting (if you want change the tintcolor) , endediting (change the tint color to norma).

Comment: @ParthoBiswas - i think you got the logic

Comment: Depending on the height of your text field, if it's the same as the "placeholder" then I would subclass `UITableViewCell`, add a `UITextField` and set the `borderStyle` of the text field to `.none`. You can add the icon to the cell or use the property `leftView` of the text field.